# How to implement a modal window in an XBAP application

Tags: c#, wpf, modal-dialog, xbap

I have a XBAP application which has the following code in a Page:

```
Person newPerson = new Person();
PersonWindow personWindow = new PersonWindow(newPerson);            
personWindow.ShowDialog();
```

When this code is invoked from a XBAP page, the resultant window does not behave like a modal window.

How can it be changed to behave like one without a significant amount of changes?

Answer (score 0):

It seems, that you have to implement the "modality" on your own, by disabling all the other window controls. [Here goes the discussion of that](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/ef66f6a7-eb9d-42f6-86ba-7fbefb72fa95/)