# Why can't I use the modal dialog (child window / top level window) in XBAP application?

Tags: c#, wpf, xbap

I have XBAP application and I wanted to understand why can't I use modal windows (child/ top level window) in spite of **Full Trust Mode**

*In other words, why the ShowDialog method is asynchronously called when used in XBAP?*

Thanks for you answer.

Comment: Please, add your actual code to allow us investigation on the problem

Answer (score 1):

The `ShowDialog` method in `XBAP` is asynchronous - this means that it returns immediately and shows a modal window (it works like in Silverlight). In `WPF` desktop application this method is synchronous - this behavior comes from the standard Window control.
The window that is shown when you call the `ShowDialog` method is still modal, no matter it is shown asynchronously.
there is a work around for that, I didn't liked it tho : [How to implement modal dialog for XBAP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/676234/how-to-implement-a-modal-window-in-an-xbap-application)

Comment: are you sure The ShowDialog method in XBAP is asynchronous? Do you have a link that mentions such?

Comment: Yes, I checked that already. I don't think that's reliable. I do not understand how come same method can be synchronous and asynchronous at the same time? It's either of those.

Comment: @ZammyPage I would say it is reliable since Its Telerik Forum admin post.It is known for the extertise in Toolkit internals. But I will try to add some more links.

Comment: Rest of the places they have mentioned that you can't(no reason specified) ,check this in infragistics - http://help.infragistics.com/Help/Doc/WPF/2012.1/CLR4.0/html/InfragisticsWPF4.v12.1~Infragistics.Windows.Controls.ToolWindow~ShowDialog.html

Comment: Okay, thanks for your efforts! However, I was behind the reason why?